# Boolean expression to threshold expression

Tags: java

I am looking for a possible way to convert a `Boolean` expression to a `threshold` expression.

for example, I got a `boolean` expresion:

```
((A & B)|(C & D)) | ((A | B) & (C | D))
```

it actually meaning choosing any two from the set of:

```
 {A,B,C,D}
```

If we use threshold expression, we can represent it as :

```
A,B,C,D 2outof4
```

But I cannot find a way to make this work.

Is there is a possible way to do it?

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Actually, what I want to know is:

given a boolean expression like:

```
((A & B)|(C & D)) | ((A | B) & (C | D))
```

is it possible to recognize the expression is actually **choose 2 element from the set {A,B,C,D}** ?

Then output something like

```
A,B,C,D 2outof4
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threshold_expression ? Google isn't very helpful here :)

Comment: Please be more specific; for example by providing an **exact** description of the result you are looking for; and then: show the code that you wrote to get there; and explain where you are stuck. This is  not a free "we implement your unclear (!) requirements for you" service!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, to summarise, you want to determine if the boolean expression is a combination generator.

I believe the code listed further below achieves this. You can see that it contains an expression with the same structure as your example:

```
or(
    or(
        and(value("A"), value("B")),
        and(value("C"), value("D"))
    ), and(
        or(value("A"), value("B")),
        or(value("C"), value("D"))
    )
);
```

which is then used as a DSL to generate the combinations:

```
{A,B}
{A,C}
{A,D}
{B,C}
{B,D}
{C,D}
```

The combinations that are generated are then checked to see if they satisfy the following:

1. Each set must have the same length - call it *r*.
2. Determine the size of the superset of unique values (e.g. "A", "B", etc) contained in the sets, call it *N*.
3. Does the number of sets equal *binomial(N, r)* - the number of ways of choosing *r* values out of *N*.

If the combinations satisfy these then the boolean expression must be a generator of choosing *r* values out of *N*.

The final line output is:

```
Optional[{A,B,C,D} 2 of 4]
```

indicating the expression is a generator for choosing 2 values out of 4.

Here is the full implementation:

```
import java.util.*;

import static java.util.Collections.singleton;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.joining;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toSet;

class Combinations {

    static <T> Set<T> union(Collection<T> lhs, Collection<T> rhs) {
        final Set<T> result = new HashSet<>(lhs);
        result.addAll(rhs);
        return result;
    }

    static <T> String collToString(Collection<T> l) {
        return l.stream()
            .map(Object::toString)
            .collect(joining(",", "{", "}"));
    }

    static <T> Set<Set<T>> value(T value) {
        return singleton(singleton(value));
    }

    static <T> Set<Set<T>> or(Set<Set<T>> lhs, Set<Set<T>> rhs) {
        return union(lhs, rhs);
    }

    static <T> Set<Set<T>> and(Set<Set<T>> lhs, Set<Set<T>> rhs) {
        return lhs.stream()
            .flatMap(ls -> rhs.stream().map(rs -> union(ls, rs)))
            .collect(toSet());
    }

    static class Choose<T> {
        private static int binomial(final int n, final int r) {
            int ret = 1;
            for (int k = 0; k < r; k++) {
                ret = ret * (n-k) /(k+1);
            }
            return ret;
        }

        static <T> Optional<Choose<T>> of(Set<Set<T>> sst) {
            final Set<Integer> sizes = sst.stream().map(Set::size).collect(toSet());
            if (sizes.size() != 1) {
                return Optional.empty();
            } else {
                final int r = sizes.iterator().next();
                final Set<T> values = sst.stream().flatMap(Set::stream).collect(toSet());
                final int n = values.size();
                final int ncr = binomial(n, r);
                if (sst.size() == ncr) {
                    return Optional.of(new Choose<>(values, r));
                } else {
                    return Optional.empty();
                }
            }
        }

        public final Set<T> values;

        public final int r;

        Choose(Set<T> values, int r) {
            this.values = values;
            this.r = r;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return collToString(values) + " " + r + " of " + values.size();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Generate the combinations.
        final Set<Set<String>> combos =
            or(
                or(
                    and(value("A"), value("B")),
                    and(value("C"), value("D"))
                ), and(
                    or(value("A"), value("B")),
                    or(value("C"), value("D"))
                )
            );

        // Print the combinations to stdout.
        combos.stream()
            .map(ss -> collToString(ss))
            .forEach(System.out::println);

        Optional<Choose<String>> choose = Choose.of(combos);
        System.out.println(choose);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the reply!
But actually what i want is like given a boolean expression like:
((A & B)|(C & D)) | ((A | B) & (C | D))

how can i recognize the expression is actually meaning :
choose any 2 element from the set {A,B,C,D}
through the program

Comment: @erick What exactly would the output be? You say it's a "threshold expression", but what is that?

Comment: Something like "(A,B,C,D) 2of4" .
Actually, I dont know how to describe this kind of expression..so I just name it as "threshold expression".

Comment: @erick I've extended the answer accordingly.

Comment: i found a problem is that: if i add one more boolean into whole expression..such as : ((A & B)|(C & D)) | ((A | B) & (C | D)) **| (E&F)**.....It cannot recognize as **((A,B,C,D) 2of4) | (E&F)**....It is because it cannot filter out the (E&F) in the program.

Comment: And I think of a method to try to solve it. For example, if I want to get the **(A,B,C,D) 2of4**, there will appear a total of 3 times of A,B,C,D in all of the combinations.....Then for the E and F, it just appear once..so I can filter it out.................But if I want to get a pattern **(A,B,C,D,E) 2of5**...the situation will much more complicated........So is there a smarter way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `Stream`, `filter` it and then `count` the elements

```
if (Stream.of(A, B, C, D).filter(x -> x).count() >= 2)
```

Comment: I would use `Function.identity()` rather than a lambda - doesn't make a huge difference, but I think it's neater.